# Batch script to copy files listed in text file from a folder and its subfolders to a new location

Tags: batch-file

I would like a batch file to copy all of the files listed in a text file from one destination to another. The source destination may have multiple subfolders and I would like the batch to search each subfolder for the file name.

I do not want copy the folders themselves, only the files.

I have the following code but it isn't recognizing the (%file_list%)

```
set src=c:\files\sourcefolder\
set dst=c:\files\destinationfolder\
set file_list=c:\\files\files.txt

for /r "%src%" %%i in (%file_list%) do copy "%%i" "%dst%" >notcopied.txt
```

I also want the file to write a text file called 'notcopied.txt' so I can see if any required files were not in the source folder. I want that file written to the destination folder.

For example:

```
files.txt contains
File1.pdf
File2.pdf
File3.pdf
```

source folder contains

```
File1.pdf
File2.pdf
```

notcopied.txt will then show

```
File3.pdf
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: To read from a text file you need a `for /F` loop, your `for /R` loop does not even access the file system (as there is no wildcard; I consider this a design flaw of `for`); so use `for /F` to walk through the `files.txt`, use `dir /B /S` to search for each item recursively and parse its output by another nested `for /F` loop. If a file is found in a sub-directory within source, do you want to copy it to the same sub-directory within destination, or is the destination flat (no sub-folders, just files)?

Comment: I'd like it to write to the new folder and not copy the same sub-directories.

Comment: So then a simple `copy` command inside the loop structure I mentioned does it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to enable **extended command line**

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
```

so you can use the extended **FOR** loop. Second, you need to enable **delayed expansion** of environment variables

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

so you can check if searched file was found later.

Here is the result:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET src=.\sourcefolder\
SET dst=.\destinationfolder\
SET file_list=.\files.txt

FOR /F %%f IN (%file_list%) DO (
    SET found=false
    FOR /F "usebackq" %%s IN (`where /R %src% %%f`) DO (
        SET found=true
        echo "%%s => %dst%\%%f"
        @copy /y "%%s" "%dst%\%%f" 
    )
    IF "!found!" == "false" (
        echo %%f is not found!
    )
)
```

**ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** is needed here for variable `%found%`, without it `%found%` will always be `false`. 
Furthermore, to expand environment at runtime you must use `!found!` syntax.

You can call it like

```
batch.bat > result.log
```

and the results will be writen to file `result.log`

---

**UPDATE**: here is a version of bacth without variable `found` and with suggestions from **@aschipfl**:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "src=.\sourcefolder\"
SET "dst=.\destinationfolder\"
SET "file_list=.\files.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%f IN ("%file_list%") DO (
    rem just searching to find out existense of file
    WHERE /Q /R "%src%" "%%f"
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
        FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%s IN (`WHERE /R "%src%" "%%f" 2^> nul`) DO (
            echo "%%s => %dst%\%%f"
            @copy /y "%%s" "%dst%\%%f" 
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo %%f is not found!
    )
)
```

This version can handle files with a `space` symbol in the filename.
But both of the solutions have same restriction: `sourcefolder` can't contain any spaces in the name. For some reason command `WHERE /R "%src%" "%%f"` doesn't working, while `WHERE /R %src% "%%f"` working just as expected.

---

**UPDATE2**: here is the version, that produces `result.log`:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "src=.\sourcefolder\"
SET "dst=.\destinationfolder\"
SET "file_list=.\files.txt"
SET "out=.\result.log"
echo > %out%

FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%f IN ("%file_list%") DO (
    rem just searching to find out existense of file
    WHERE /Q /R %src% "%%f"
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
        FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%s IN (`WHERE /R %src% "%%f"`) DO (
            echo "%%s => %dst%\%%f" >> %out%
            @copy /y "%%s" "%dst%\%%f" 
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo %%f is not found! >> %out%
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code! I'm not around my computer but will try it when I can. Where would I put the '> result.log' in that code to output the file?

Comment: `result.log` will be created automatically in the folder with `batch.bat`

Comment: Great idea to use `where`! I think variable `found` is not necessary as `where` throws an error in case of no match anyway; and you should add options `delims=` (to disable default delimiters _space_ and _tab_) and `eol=|` (to not use default char. `;`) to both `for /F` loops... you could also combine the two `setlocal` commands to a single one (state both arguments)...

Comment: In fact, variable `found` is necessary, because I need to show that some files are not found in the log. To remove `found` there is a different approach, updated my answer with it and your suggestions.

Comment: @spirit, I edited your answer because you had a typo (?) in the `delims` options and I added the `eol` options; in addition, I improved the quotes-handling of the first `for /F` loop and I changed the syntax of the `set` command lines in terms of quoting...

Comment: @aschipfl, why did you use `eol=|`? Why you don't like default char of `;`? Btw, `delim==` in not a typo, it's taken from the `FOR /?` help. As they say `FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`set`) DO @echo %i`.

Comment: 1. `delims==` sets the delimiter to `=`, so every path or file name containing `=` will be split; `delims=` disables the delimiter. 2. Paths or file names could also begin with the default `eol`character `;`, so they would be ignored; the `|` is a forbidden characters in paths or file names, so no items will be ignored...

Comment: @vonN00B, if you'll find my answed useful, please accept it as a correct one.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to use another `where` command line to get the `ErrorLevel`; instead remove the entire `if !ErrorLevel!`/`else` construct, put the entire `for /F %%s` loop in between `()` and append ` || echo %%f is not found!` to the closing `)`, because: 1. the `ErrorLevel` of the remaining `where` command line in the `for /F %%s` loop is available anyway; 2. in case of no match, the body of the loop is not executed; 3. [`||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) executes the following command only in case of a non-zero `ErrorLevel` (short for `if !ErrorLevel! NEQ 0`);

Comment: @vonN00B. did you tried to add `file*.*` to your `files.txt`? It works.

Comment: Thanks so much @spirit.
I marked your answer as correct and have it working. The only thing I can't still get is the result.log. Am I supposed to put > result.log somewhere in the coding? I tried running from cmd line, and also just running batch and it doesn't write. Can't see anywhere in the code it would write to a file.

Comment: @spirit, I ended up getting the text to not have the extension working by putting .* after each %%f starting in the where loop

Comment: to get the result writed in the `result.log` you must run batch file like this: `c:\>batch.bat > result.log`

Comment: is there no way to get it so I can just run the batch file and get a log or text file?
If I put echo %%f is not found! > results.txt it will show only the last plan in a file it writes, can I append to the existing file each time that else statement is used? There will be other people using this who won't get a cmd line

Comment: @vonN00B, I've updated my answer. See **UPDATE2** block.