# Batch file to copy files listed in a text file from source to destination keeping the folder structure

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file to copy files listed in a text file from a source folder to a destination folder. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128220/batch-script-to-copy-files-listed-in-text-file-from-a-folder-and-its-subfolders) but this doesn't copy the folders.

Right now I have the code below and it searches for the files in the list in the source folders but it then copies them to the destination folder but I get just the files, not the folders.

**Destination Folder**, and the **File List** reside under **different paths**:

```
File list:         W:\Parrot EN VO\Copylist.txt

DestinationFolder: W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4test
```

And **File List points to files in different locations** (sometimes the file names are the same but they are in different folders):

```
W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4_VO4b\Actor_A\file1.wav

W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4_VO4b\Actor_B\file1.wav

W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4_VO4b\Actor_B\file2.wav

W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4_VO4b\Actor_C\file1.wav
```

this is the code I have:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "W:\Parrot EN VO\Copylist.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4test"
```

pause

Thanks!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to be able to copy the files and the folders. The code I had before was only copying the files but not the folders. I found out how to do it, though. thanks!

Comment: …but `Copylist.txt` appears to only contain **files**, how is the script supposed to know that you're also wanting to copy some **folders** which aren't in the list?

Comment: I wonder :) I'm not a programmer, I'm learning and I do this when I have some time. I guess I will have to study and try more. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to start from scratch with a different approach and with help from another answer that I saw I managed to make it work:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source=input dir"
set "target=output dir"

for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%A in ("file_list.txt") do (
set "FILE=%%A"
set "dest_file_full=%target%\!FILE:%source%=!"
set "dest_file_filename=%%~nxA"
call set "dest_file_dir=%%dest_file_full:!dest_file_filename!=%%"
if not exist "!dest_file_dir!" (
    md "!dest_file_dir!"
)
set "source_file_full=%source%\!FILE:%source%=!"
copy "!source_file_full!" "!dest_file_dir!"
)
pause
```